# Fortran with MPI error

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am working on Fortran code with MPI and introducing the following MPI command

```
    call MPI_Gather(nlocal,1,MPI_INTEGER,counts,1,MPI_INTEGER,0&
         &,comm_cart,ierror)
```

with in a particular `subroutine` gives following error:

```
This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [MPI_INTEGER]
```

I understand that the compiler does not recognize the MPI part of this code. However, all other related variables such as `nlocal, counts and comm_cart` are recognized except the Fortran MPI data type `MPI_INTEGER`. Can someone throw light, where I am doing wrong?

Note: The compiler is Intel compiler

Comment: How are you including MPI_INTEGER in the variable space?

Comment: You should always show more of your code, namely, where do all your symbols come from and where are your statements placed. The downvotes probably come from this failure to show all relevant details. The problem itself is legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must tell the compiler about the MPI stuff (mainly variables).

The modern way is introducing

```
use mpi
```

in every scope.

In the old days it was also done using

```
include "mpif.h"
```

but that has several disadvantages. Namely, because it is compatible with FORTRAN 77, it does not introduce explicit interfaces for any MPI subroutines and therefore the error checking is less thorough than with `use mpi`. The modern method will help you more in keeping your code correct.

On the other hand, if you use `use mpi` the module `mpi` must be compiled with the same compiler (sometimes even with the same version) which you use to compile your program.